# Get XPath of Child node only by passing partial node name

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I Have following XML Stored in MarkLogic,

```
<testDoc>
    <test>
        <test1>test1</test1>
        <test2>test2</test2>
        <test3>test3</test3>
    </test>
</testDoc>
```

My Requirement is to get the xpath of child nodes only like, if i pass test(**partial node name**) to my xquery then i am expecting

```
/testDoc/test/test1
/testDoc/test/test2
/testDoc/test/test3
```

but my xquery returning,

```
/testDoc
/testDoc/test
/testDoc/test/test1
/testDoc/test/test2
/testDoc/test/test3
```

XQuery I am Executing on qconsole is,

```
 xquery version "1.0-ml";
 let $xml := document { fn:doc("/test/testDoc")}
 let $elem-name := "test"
 let $elems := $xml//*[local-name()[contains(lower-case(.), lower-case($elem-name))]]
 return $elems ! xdmp:path(.)
```

Please guide me to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are trying to match at a certain depth or just the leaf nodes. If you only want to get the leaf nodes, you can add a predicate to check that there are no child elements

```
[fn:not(./*)]
```

You can also rewrite your predicates and use `fn:matches()` to do the match

```
let $elems := $xml//*[fn:not(./*)][fn:matches(fn:local-name(.), $elem-name, "i")]
```

Comment: @Shiv could you mark this question as answered, please? That lets people know that you're not still looking for help (and gives James some credit).

Comment: @Dave Cassel... Yes... I Already marked this question as answered.

Comment: Thank u @James Kerr.. Your solution is working as per my Expectation.